# Duplicate A6 booklets on A4 paper

Tags: pdfpages, booklet

how can I duplicate A6 size book one below the other on A4 paper? I would like to receive two A6 format of the same brochures printed from ordinary A4 format file. Like this:

[image]

And so on..
What I was able to achieve below but it's printing only one copy and in incorrect order.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
\end{document}
```

Then I've tried this for 10 pages, it works, but what If I get 20,50 or more? Can I automate this for any count of pages in file? Some macro of lastpage?

```
\includepdf[pages={10,1,10,1}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
\includepdf[pages={2,9,2,9}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
\includepdf[pages={8,3,8,3}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
\includepdf[pages={4,7,4,7}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
\includepdf[pages={6,5,6,5}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
```

Comment: It will probably not work out of the box as it is a bit unusual. Might be easier to simply generate the setup output page by output page (aka many calls to `\includepdf`)

Comment: I had to write 10 lines of code manually when I have 24 pages. I need to somehow automate this process as I get more pages. Maybe some macros of lastpage?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the `booklet` package to produce the PDF of an A5 booklet (2 A5 pages per A4) and then rescale this PDF and combine two of them (4 A6 pages per A4)? Not a fully automatic solution, of course.

Comment: @Ingmar it's some kind of idea but I need to automate this process

Comment: The arrangement of the second page doesn't make any sense to me. Shouldn't left and right be swapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your document in A6 format first.

File `t1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-13]
\end{document}
```

Then create *one* booklet in A5 format.

File `t2.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{\ifodd\c@page\PLS@Rotate{180}\else\PLS@Rotate{0}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet]{t1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Finally doublicate all pages of the booklet.

File `t3.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,doublepages,nup=1x2]{t2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not an option. I have to use a premade A4 pdf file. It is a complex template with two columns of text, multiple drawings and font sizes. When I changed the format from A4 to A6, it all fell apart.

Comment: You can start with A4 as well. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I skipped the first step with creating an A6 file and I included my A4 pdf file in the t2.tex file, then duplicated it in t3 and it seems to work as I wanted. I understand that these two steps t2 and t3 cannot be combined into one file?

Comment: It can only be done in one step if you calculate the sequence of pages yourself and put the resulting list into `pages={...}`.

Comment: Thank you for that solution!

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
\includepdf[pages={4,1,4,1}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
\includepdf[pages={3,2,3,2}, nup=2x2]{a4papersample}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I had to write 10 lines of code manually when I have 24 pages. I need to somehow automate this process as I get more pages. Maybe some macros of lastpage?