# To print "in-quarto"

Tags: books, book-design, printing

I would like to print "in-quarto". I explain briefly, I would like to print a A6-book, therefore I would like to print the A6 pages of my book on A4 pages (2 sides) and then fold twice the printed folio to obtain a booklet of 8 pages, then I need to open the upper side of the book with a knife (or a guillotine paper). This is the old fashion to print books.
[A good scheme is better than a long talk](https://neptun.unamur.be/themes/neptun/asset/images/plantin/Image%20In-quarto.jpg). How to print like that ?
My solution is to process twice my document through the command `\pdfinclude` (with the booklet option in two different .tex file.
Is there an easier way ?

Subsidiary question, how to do it easily for an in-octovo ? i.e. same thing but you have 8 pages on each side of the folio and you need to fold the folio 3 times.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages ?

Comment: Indeed, ```pgfmorepages``` can make the job, even if it is not a simple option. I found the solution in this answer given by @AndrewStacey here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638802/two-sided-printing-of-a6-pages-on-a4-paper/639168#639168

Comment: Great to hear you were able to solve your problem! Do you consider the questions to be similar enough to mark them as duplicate or is your solution unique enough that it would be better for you to write a self answer?